# Using listview inside sliverlist in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-sliver

I'm currently using **vertical_scrollable_tabview widget**. 
It uses a sliverList to build the list.
The list I need to use contains a list of object, so I need a way to implement a listview inside of this sliverlist.
This list of object is dynamic, so I can't use a fixed heigth to define it. Is there a way to control the list (it should be unscrollable, sliverlist should scroll).
What I am actually using is this, but it's very bad

```
  return Container(
    height: (tabEmersy!.text.length < 50)? 50 : 30* (tabEmersy!.text.length/50);
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-40,
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: tabEmersy.content.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return _testBuildContentDetail(
            context: context,
            content: tabEmersy.content[index]);
      }
  ),
);

Widget _testBuildContentDetail({
required BuildContext context,
required Contentemersy content,
}) {
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    content.title!=null?
    Text(content.title!, style: _textTheme(context).titleMedium):SizedBox(height: 0,),
    const SizedBox(height: 2),
    Html(...),
  ],
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your proposal, you can use Column

```dart
return Container(
    // height: (tabEmersy!.text.length < 50)? 50 : 30* (tabEmersy!.text.length/50);
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-40,
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    child: Column(
     children: List.generate(tabEmersy.content.length, (index)   {
        return _testBuildContentDetail(
```